# Cross product of nested arrays to flat table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have nested objects, depth of objects can be N, each object can have X properties as well as X objects nested to it.

**Problem**

1) I am having trouble guessing what column headers will be added to my table until the whole loop is completed. As you can see in my first row, I only had 1 column "Name" but in 2nd row I had nested objects which added more column headers to table.

2) I want to make it work with jQuery datatable which doesn't work with above scenario, as all rows doesn't have same number of columns

3) I don't want to hard code anything as JSON data can be anything.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jwf347a4/8/

***Please note that JSON is dynamic, syntax will remain same but number of objects and properties + number of child objects can vary, so no hard coding... thanks***

**Code**

```
var resultFromWebService = {
  //"odata.metadata": "http://localhost:21088/WcfDataService1.svc/$metadata#Categories&$select=Name,Products,Products/Currency/Symbol",
  "value": [{
    "Products": [],
    "Name": "Meat"
  }, {
    "Products": [{
      "Currency": {
        "ID": 47,
        "Num": 826,
        "Code": "GBP",
        "Description": "United Kingdom Pound",
        "DigitsAfterDecimal": 2,
        "Symbol": "\u00a3",
        "Hide": null,
        "Priority": 1
      },
      "ID": 2425,
      "Name": "303783",
      "ExpiryDate": "2014-02-22T00:00:00",
      "CurrencyID": 47,
      "Sales": "0.00000000000000000000",
      "PreTaxProfitOnProduct": null,
      "Assets": "0.30000000000000000000",
      "BarCode": null,
      "Worth": "0.20000000000000000000",
      "MarketValue": null
    }],
    "Name": "Produce & Vegetable"
  }]
};


var createBody = true;
var $table = $('<table id="myTable" class="defaultResultsFormatting"/>');
var $thead = $('<thead />');
var $tbody = $('<tbody />');
var $headRow = $('<tr/>');
var $parentCells = null;
var columnHeaders = [];
$table.append($thead);
var $resultContainer = createResultsTable(resultFromWebService);
$("#resultTableContainer").append($resultContainer);

//$('#myTable').dataTable();

function createResultsTable(data, title) {
  if (data) { // && data.length > 0) {
    if (createBody) {
      $thead.append($headRow);
      $table.append($tbody);
      createBody = false;
    }
    if (data.length > 0) {
      addColumnHeaders(data[0]);
      $.each(data, function(index, e) {
        populateTable(e);
      });
    } else {
      addColumnHeaders(data);
      populateTable(data);
    }
  } else {
    this.noResults();
  }

  function addColumnHeaders(result) {
    for (var property in result) {
      var type = typeof result[property];
      if (type === 'string' || type === 'number' || type === 'boolean' || result[property] instanceof Date || !result[property]) {
        var mainEntityName = result.__metadata ? result.__metadata.type.split(".").splice(-1)[0] + "." : "";
        mainEntityName = (title ? title + "." : mainEntityName);
        var cName = mainEntityName + property;
        if ($.inArray(cName, columnHeaders) < 0) {
          $headRow.append($('<th />', {
            text: cName
          }));
          columnHeaders.push(cName);
          console.log("columnHeader:" + cName);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function populateTable(data) {
    var $bodyRow = null;
    if ($parentCells) {
      $bodyRow = $parentCells.clone();
    } else {
      $bodyRow = $('<tr/>');
    }

    var expandedChildResults = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, property) {
      var type = typeof property;
      if (type === 'string' || type === 'number' || type === 'boolean') {
        $bodyRow.append($('<td />', {
          text: property
        }));
      } else if (property instanceof Date) { // DataJS returns the dates as objects and not as strings.
        $bodyRow.append($('<td />', {
          text: property.toDateString()
        }));
      } else if (!property) {
        $bodyRow.append('<td />');
      } else if (typeof property === 'object' && property.results && index !== '__metadata') {
        expandedChildResults.push({
          key: property.results,
          value: index
        });
      } else if (typeof property === 'object' && index !== '__metadata' && index !== '__deferred' && !isPropertyAnObjectWithJustSingle__deferred(property)) {
        expandedChildResults.push({
          key: property,
          value: index
        });
      }
    });

    if (expandedChildResults.length > 0) {
      $.each(expandedChildResults, function(index, childObject) {
        $parentCells = $bodyRow;
        createResultsTable(childObject.key, childObject.value);
      });
      $parentCells = null;
    } else
      $tbody.append($bodyRow);
      console.log($bodyRow);
  }

  function isPropertyAnObjectWithJustSingle__deferred(property) {
    var keys;
    return typeof property === 'object' && // test if it's and object
      (keys = Object.keys(property)).length === 1 && // test if it has just sibgle property
      keys[0] === '__deferred'; // test if that property is '__deferred'
  }

  return $table;
};
```

**Biggest Problem / Summary**

The problem where I stuck is that I am not sure how to add empty cells to rows once whole table object is built, otherwise jQuery datable won't like it.

**Update**

Current answer doesn't works when I have more then 1 nested child arrays and so on...

https://jsfiddle.net/1tsu6xt9/46/

As you can see there is only 1 row, I want it to show 3, like I have in this fiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/jwf347a4/24/

Comment: what is the problem that you are not able to resolve?? initilizing datatables to this table? is that the only problem you have?

Comment: @Reddy my main issue is to add empty cells to rows once whole table object is built, otherwise jQuery datable won't like it

Comment: Yes, I understand that.. Just wanted to confirm if you have any other issue.. I will give you a solution in few minutes

Answer (score 2):

I propose keeping track of which columns already exist, and using that to detect when you need to inject a new column or skip over unused columns.

### [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1tsu6xt9/7/)

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var activeColumns = [],
        injectedColumns = [];

    var testData = [{
        "Products": [],
        "ID": 999,
        "Name": "Grocery"
    }, {
        "Products": [],
        "Name": "Meat"
    }, {
        "Products": [{
            "Currency": {
                "ID": 47,
                "Num": 826,
                "Code": "GBP",
                "Description": "United Kingdom Pound",
                "DigitsAfterDecimal": 2,
                "Symbol": "\u00a3",
                "Hide": null,
                "Priority": 1
            },
            "ID": 2425,
            "Name": "303783",
            "ExpiryDate": "2014-02-22T00:00:00",
            "CurrencyID": 47,
            "Sales": "0.00000000000000000000",
            "PreTaxProfitOnProduct": null,
            "Assets": "0.30000000000000000000",
            "BarCode": null,
            "Worth": "0.20000000000000000000",
            "MarketValue": null
        }],
        "Name": "Produce & Vegetable"
    }];

    var rows = testData.reduce(function(rows, row) {
        return appendRow(rows, flattenRecord({}, row));
    }, []);

    injectedColumns.forEach(function(ic) {
        rows.slice(0, ic.end).forEach(function(row) {
            var tds = row.find('td'),
                adjacentTo = ic.idx < tds.length ? tds[ic.idx] : null;
            if (adjacentTo) {
                $('<td/>', {
                    insertBefore: adjacentTo
                });
            } else {
                $('<td/>', {
                    appendTo: row
                });
            }
        });
    });

    var table = $('<table/>', {
        append: rows,
        appendTo: 'body'
    });


    var headingRow = $('<tr/>', {
        prependTo: table
    });

    activeColumns.forEach(function(name) {
        $('<th/>', {
            text: name,
            appendTo: headingRow
        });
    });

    function flattenRecord(result, rec) {
        return Object.keys(rec).reduce(function(result, key) {
            var value = rec[key];
            if (value && typeof value === 'object')
                flattenRecord(result, value);
            else
                result[key] = value;
            return result;
        }, result);
    }

    function injectColumn(key, idx, end) {
        injectedColumns.push({
            key: key,
            idx: idx,
            end: end
        });
    }

    function appendRow(rows, obj) {
        var inputColumns = Object.keys(obj),
            tr = $('<tr/>'),
            outputCol;

        outputCol = 0;
        inputColumns.forEach(function(key) {
            var value = obj[key],
                cell,
                activeSrch = activeColumns.indexOf(key),
                emptyCells = activeSrch >= 0 ? activeSrch - outputCol : 0,
                i;
            for (i = 0; i < emptyCells; ++i, ++outputCol) {
                $('<td/>', {
                    appendTo: tr
                });
            }

            if (activeColumns[outputCol] !== key) {
                activeColumns.splice(outputCol, 0, key);
                injectColumn(key, outputCol, rows.length);
            }
            cell = $('<td/>', {
                text: value,
                appendTo: tr
            });
            ++outputCol;
        });

        rows.push(tr);

        return rows;
    }
}());
```

#### How it works

First it flattens the records to get rid of the nesting.

Then, for each column, see if that column already exists.

If that column exists, see if we are skipping over columns. If so, we skip forward that many and insert that many empty cells. If not, we remember which row we are on so we can insert a cell in all previous rows, at the appropriate index.

Comment: it seems to be working for the scenario, I will do more testing and come back to you, thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** (**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwf347a4/12/)**) Once you have built your table call another function which will complete the table by **adding missing cells into the rows**

This logic must help.

```
function RestructureTheDynamicTable(){
 var $table = $('#myTable');
 var maxColumns = $table.find('thead tr th').length;    //find the total columns required

  $table.find('tbody tr').each(function(){
    var thisRowColumnCount = $(this).find('td').length;
    var extraTds = "";
    if(maxColumns > thisRowColumnCount){    //if this row doesn't have the required number of columns lets add them
      for(var i=0;i < maxColumns - thisRowColumnCount;i++){
        extraTds += "<td></td>";
      }
      $(this).append(extraTds);
    }    
  });
}
```

***Call this function after you have completed building the table. After the table completes restructuring then you can apply the Datatables plugin***

Comment: Thank you Reddy, it looks good, but it adds columns at the end, whereas the dataset can have different columns for different objects, please see this example - https://jsfiddle.net/jwf347a4/15/

Comment: I think I need to add data-attributes to each cell, so that it would know which header it needs to go with, but I am not sure how to implement it

Comment: @Mathematics I changed the fiddle link.. I think you are still seeing the older version of my code.. see the latest.. I have handled that part too, the change is this line `var maxColumns = $table.find('thead tr th').length;`

Comment: please see I am testing with with latest fiddle but it's not working... http://prnt.sc/b91epb

Comment: @Mathematics oh I see, I was talking about the improper columns at the end

Comment: @Mathematics that seems to be part of your existing logic, and its so difficult to understand :)... I will try my best